# Cannot import module in powershell - failed to load files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a function in a specific module of powershell that I had installed on my computer. 
Through the PowerShell window it works well but while using PowerGUI it fails.

While trying to execute:

```
Import-Module modulename
```

I got the exception:
There were errors in loading the format dtat file:
Microsoft.PowerShell, the path of: modulename.format.pslxmml: File skipped because it was already present from "Microsoft.PowerShell".

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you use Update-FormatData or Update-TypeData within the .psm1 file, which will prevent the module from loading twice because you cannot re-register formatting information.  To make this work, use the .psd1 file to specify the types and formats files:

```
@{
    ModuleToProcess='MyModule.psm1'
    ModuleVersion = '1.0'
    FormatsToProcess = MyModule.Format.ps1xml'
    TypesToProcess = 'MyModule.Types.ps1xml'
}
```

Please note that this sort of bug is rather pervasive in published modules.  So if your module doesn't have formatting, but imports another module, then you'll have to modify that module to import it's formatters correctly.